# Loop through json array and insert into mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

I am trying to insert a record into mysql using php but I don't know how to achieve this in php:
Basically I have the following json array:

```
[{StudentId:236,"Monday":null,"Tuesday":"2","Wednesday":"3","Thursday":"4","Friday":null},{StudentId:237,"Monday":null,"Tuesday":null,"Wednesday":"3","Thursday":"4","Friday":"5"}]
```

MySQL table schema is below:

Id | Student | Day

1  | 236     | 2

2  | 236     | 3

3  | 236     | 4

4 | 237 | 3

5 | 237 | 4

I am using the following code to loop through and get the values out but it is not showing for each day. Should I create another array of all the days the student is attending and then loop through? Please and advise would be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
$arr = json_decode($output,true);
foreach ($arr as $key => $jsons)
    {
        $day=null;
        $student=null;

        foreach($jsons as $key => $value)
        {
            if($key == 'StudentId')
            {
                $student = $value;
            }

            if($key == 'Monday')
            {
              if($value == '1')
              {
                 $day = 1;
              }
            }

            if($key == 'Tuesday')
            {
               if($value == '2')
               {
                   $day = 2;
               }
             }
        }
        echo "INSERT INTO MyTable (Student,Day) VALUES($student,$day);";
        echo '<br/>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of arrays of key/value pairs, but according to your code you have two arrays of key/value pairs.  See how the following affects your code, and throw in a `print` statement or two to help debug.

Change:  `foreach ($arr as $key => $jsons)`

to:  `foreach ($arr as $jsons)`

Comment: Actually it is an object inside array with index 0, 1, 2 etc

Answer (score 0):

it looks like You have malformed JSON string. This sample works fine:

```
$json = <<<JSON
[
  {
    "StudentId": 236,
    "Monday": null,
    "Tuesday": "2",
    "Wednesday": "3",
    "Thursday": "4",
    "Friday": null
  },
  {
    "StudentId": 237,
    "Monday": null,
    "Tuesday": null,
    "Wednesday": "3",
    "Thursday": "4",
    "Friday": "5"
  }
]
JSON;

$arr = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($arr as $student) {
    foreach ($student as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == 'StudentId') {
            $student = $value;
        }

        if ($key == 'Monday') {
            if ($value == '1') {
                $day = 1;
            }
        }

        if ($key == 'Tuesday') {
            if ($value == '2') {
                $day = 2;
            }
        }
    }
    echo "INSERT INTO MyTable (Student,Day) VALUES($student,$day);\n";
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

And the result is:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Student,Day) VALUES(236,2);
INSERT INTO MyTable (Student,Day) VALUES(237,2);
```